# Spring boot with Hibernate envers: all fields in audit table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to have an audit table with all the column of the base table, that is updated only when a specific column is modified? If I add the @Audited annotation to my Entity class I have an audit table with all the columns, but a new row is inserted every time a field is modified; otherwise, if I add the @Audited annotation only to one property, hibernate will add a new row inside the audit table only when that property is modified, but the audit table will have only one column ( the column of the property annotated). Any suggestion?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: use @NotAudited for fields that you do not want ot audit.